# Font awesome icons not showing on IE9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, font-awesome

I have used font-awesome-rails gem(3.2.1) for my rails application to add font awesome icons, icons loaded in chrome & FF but not in IE 9

Comment: have you seen that? https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#ie7-support

Comment: added that file also but still not getting icons